# How to report errors (Java using log4j), conveying information about an error

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have seen a lot of information using log4j for logging errors and information but I have seen little information on what to actually put in a error report.

I guess it depends on the domain, but what are your best practices for reporting an issue.

If I am on a web application server, how do you normally log errors?

I think just reporting the exception stack trace is a bad practice.

So far, I normally include:

- Call calling class or method that generated the error. Some report
- error id (E.g. EID=0093) and then mapping the error id to some external documentation
- Processing time at of error (if available, how
  long did the previous function call take to execute)
- Directory and file information.  If I am working with a file, I try to report the
  full path of the file in the event of file not found errors

Comment: Provide enough information to understand what may have gone wrong if it's an error, or enough information to be useful if it's for reporting app flow. The question is so specific to the app in question I'm not sure how it can be answered usefully.

Comment: Do you mean in the logs or an error report back to the user?

Comment: This will naturally depend on your business process. Where I currently work, any unusual errors will be passed on to developers anyway, so I design error-messages to be optimal for someone with access to the code, chiefly adding information that's not implicit in the call stack. (If an error happens a lot, then Field Support will become familiar with it no matter how I've designed the error-message.) But at many companies Field Support doesn't have such ready access to developers -- and many companies develop software that customers have to manage. So there's no one answer.

Comment: No, not to the user but to the developer.

Comment: OK ruakh, for your example, what information did you provide, could be more specific?